# jQuery plugin template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've found this template for creating jQuery plugin http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/

But I don't understand in code, why we declare pluginName like a method of jQuery object and then we declare pluginName like a method of object $.fn why we did that?

Comment: It seems pretty well documented. Maybe you should also consider the jQuery documentation about plugins: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the plugin to `$` enables you to write:

```
var $el = $(".myselector");
$.myplugin($el, {
  some: "option",
  another: "one"
});
```

Adding the plugin to `$.fn` enables you to write:

```
$(".myselector").myplugin({
  some: "option",
  another: "one"
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I still do not understand why we use these two declaration in this plugin template

Comment: We use these two declarations to support both syntax (as shown above).